# What SQL query should I use to output the value of my 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a student and is new to MySQL

I have 2 tables, ors_uniform contains 7 products that has 9 sizes (XS-5XL).

ors_prices contains the fk of table1 and the prices per size (9 sizes)

I wanted it so that when I output the inventory of the products, the price will be shown next to it. I know how to do that using php already but I don't know what MySQL query to use.

I currently just use `SELECT * FROM ors_uniform`

[2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B88dt.png)

Comment: This is a basic `join` between the two tables.

Comment: The *size* columns on your `ors_uniform` table are redundant and should be normalised.

Comment: what does it mean @Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume the `fk` is a foreign key and it is available in both tables.

`select * from ors_uniform join ors_prices on ors_uniform.fk = ors_prices.fk;`